# Linux Mint Debian Edition: GRUB Error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found

Tags: linux, linux-mint, grub, lmde

I installed LMDE on my computer using LMDE official live usb image. I made /, /home, /swap, something about booting. The installation was very successful, there was no any errors while installing. But when I boot with GRUB, there is error like that

```
GRUB loading.
Welcome to GRUB!

error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> _
```

Comment: Possible duplicate?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Wel there are multiple questions like this one

Comment: Sadly I could not find question like this one. I couldn't understand them. Can I have your answer if you have professional knowledge about this one please?

Comment: I know the issue again, wait a sec and I'll post it.

Comment: Posted the fix for this issue

Comment: It maybe because you used fat32, but try my fix first then I'll retry to fix it.

Comment: Why no comments?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is happening if the boot loader is set to install on /dev/sda1 instead of /dev/sda in example.

Here are the steps to resolve it
Boot from the install media.
Choose try LMDE (or any other distro) first.

```
mount /dev/sdx1 /mnt/
```

Where x stands for the letter of the partition.

```
mount /dev/sdx2 /mnt/boot/   
mount /dev/sdx3 /mnt/home/
```

(Oy if you use separate partitions

```
cd /mnt
mount -t proc /proc proc/
mount --rbind /sys sys/
mount --rbind /dev dev/
mount --rbind /run run/
cp /etc/resolv.conf etc/resolv.conf
```

(For wireless)

Then do

```
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

After this use the commands:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

(Or any other partition you use, only with Debian based distro's)

This should work, if not comment again.